# Eigenvalue and algebraic multiplicity

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a symmetric and invertible matrix. $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times n}$.
$$B=A+\alpha^{T}\alpha A^{-1}$$

1. All eigenvalues of $B$ are real.
2. If $a$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with algebraic multiplicity $k$, then it is also an eigenvalue of $B$ with multiplicity at least $k-1$.

I got stucked at the beginning since $B$ is not always symmetric.

Comment: Why is it not symmetric?

Comment: I think you can start by proving that $A$ and $A^{-1}$ have the same eigenvectors

Comment: Just multilpy $A^{-1}$ to both side of $A\lambda = k\lambda$. I have no idea on handling $\alpha^{T}\alpha$ which is a $n\times n$ matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hints.* (I am more accustomed to the convention that a vector in $\mathbb R^n$ denoted by a single letter is a column vector. So, I will write $B=A+uu^TA^{-1}$ instead, where $u=\alpha^T\in\mathbb R^{n\times1}$ is a column vector.)

1. Note that $A^2+uu^T$ is positive definite. Hence $B=(A^2+uu^T)A^{-1}$ is similar to some real symmetric matrix.
2. Let $X\in \mathbb R^{n\times k}$ be a matrix whose $k$ columns span the eigenspace of $A$ for the eigenvalue $a$. Then
   $$
   BXv=aXv+uu^TXv
   $$
   for any $v\in\mathbb R^k$. What is the dimension of the subspace of all vectors $v$ such that $u^TXv=0$?

Comment: I find it hard to understand why $B=(A^2+uu^T)A^{-1}$ is similar to a symmetric matrix...

Comment: @JeanMarie It is similar to $(A^2+uu^T)^{1/2}A^{-1}(A^2+uu^T)^{1/2}$.

Comment: Thank you: I wasn't thinking to this possibility...

Comment: @JeanMarie There exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $A^2+uu^T=PP^T$, thus $B=PP^TA^{-1}$ is similar to $P^{-1}BP=P^TA^{-1}P$.