# All eigenvalues are real

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

> Let matrix $A \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$ be symmetric, vector $\alpha \in \Bbb R^n$ have unit Euclidean norm, and $$B = A + \alpha\alpha^TA^{-1}$$ Show all eigenvalues of $B$ are real.

---

I have made some attempts:1.B is not symmetric in general.2.Let $P$ be an orthogonal s.t.

$$P^{-1} A P = D = \mbox{diag} \left( \lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n \right)$$

by $A$ symmetric we have all $\lambda$s are real. But I can't work it out after some calculations.

Comment: For your first question, someone (probably your classmate) asked [the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4049910) two hours ago. I've given an answer to that question.